# Eclipse deploys content of WebContent folder to WEB-INF folder.

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-inf

I encounter a strange behaviour of the Eclipse `Run on Server` feature. My environment:

- `Eclipse Kepler SR 1, WTP`
- `Apache Tomcat 7.0.37`

I have two dynamic web projects inside Eclipse - `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. Both have an `index.xhtml` file (indeed both projects are JSF projects) directly below the `WebContent` folder. When I export them as `WAR`files to the `Tomcat webapps` folder of the Tomcat installation, both run fine. When I run `ProjectA` on the Tomcat server managed by Eclipse through `Run on Server` feature, everything is also fine. But when I want to start `ProjectB` from Eclipse through `Run on Server` I get a `404 error` when accessing the `http://localhost:8080/ProjectB/index.xhtml` or respectively an `index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource` error from the JSF servlet when accessing the resource through the correct `http://localhost:8080/ProjectB/faces/index.xhtml` URL. (All URLs starting with `/faces/` are matched to the `JSF Servlet`.

Looking at the deployed application in the Tomcat folder in the Eclipse Workspace ( `<eclipse-workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`) reveals the cause:
For `ProjectB` the content of the Eclipse projects `WebContent` folder has been deployed to the `WEB-INF` folder instead to the root folder of the projects deployment. The application server of course can not find the resource.

The question is - **Why does the deployment fail and how can I avoid this?**

I even checked the `Deployment Assembly` property of both projects inside eclipse. Both have the same (default) source-to-destination-folder mapping. Here is the content of the `.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
<wb-module deploy-name="ProfileAndGroupManagementGUI">
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
    <property name="context-root" value="ProfileAndGroupManagementGUI"/>
    <property name="java-output-path" value="/ProfileAndGroupManagementGUI/build/classes"/>
</wb-module>
```

Strange, isn´t it? Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
```

tells `wst` to package your sources to `/WEB-INF/classes`, that's what you don't want to do as this is a lib project. Changing it to

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src"/>
```

will do the trick.